# Recommended tools for web development with python under linux?

Tags: python, linux

I'm planning to work on a project using Tornado / nginx / mySQL / jQuery and would be using linux (im new to linux too, i barely know what vim / emacs are). Which tools for web development with this stack would you recommend?

Comment: I can't answer this question without thinking of the [flame war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war) it will likely touch off.

Comment: I prefer `nano` over `emacs` and `vim` ;)

Comment: Check out pycharm IDE . Its has FOSS versionn https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

Answer (score 2):

I use [gedit](http://www.gedit.org) for most of my web programming. I know, it's not very hardcore, but it has syntax highlighting and some nice plugins and it's very user-friendly.

I would recommend learning to use bash, ssh, and the mysql console especially. It beats any sort of database gui, hands down.

Besides that and a web browser... well, that's it, really. Make sure you're using chrome's developer tools, or [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) if you're using firefox.

Comment: +1 for gedit. I just posted the same thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can help you out with Python, MySQL, and JQuery.

[Python ID - Pydev](http://pydev.org/)

[Eclipse Data Tools Platform (MySQL)](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/)

In addition you could use [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're asking exactly, but I do all my web development with [gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

**Gedit** has plugins for an embedded terminal, running code with keyboard shortcuts, and a really minimalistic interface. Here's a screenshot with the Oblivion theme:

[image]

**Flask** is just an amazing web framework. It's simple, fast, and easy to understand. I built a blogging application in less than 20 minutes with it!

Here's a completely self-sufficient application:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the vote for Eclipse above, if you are looking for an alternative for gedit, I'd recommend Geany: http://www.geany.org/

I very much agree on using Firebug, and I'd also add the Web Developer toolbar if you're using Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a lot more problems than your choice of framework if this is your first project on a UNIX. I'd recommend you find a clued in person at your workplace who knows the platform fairly well and use her as a teacher rather than rely completely on the web.